# Updating ImageView and TextView OnClick for a Single Card in RecyclerView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I have an app that I want to do the following:

**When the user clicks on a star imageView it updates the server (adds posts to my *favoritePosts*, and +1 to *likesCounter*), but it should also update the imageView (liked to  unliked and vice versa), and the textView with the number of likes on the cardView I clicked.**

Currently, the imageView changes, and it updates server correctly, but there are some things that do not work the way they should, such as:

***Some titles disappear and reappear when I click the star imageView (to add posts to favorites), and the textView is almost never updated at all, and when it is, it sometimes decreases instead of increasing and vice versa.*** In my database it is updated correctly, like is added/removed correctly, likes counter is updated correctly, also when I exit and reenter the activity it is updated correctly.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457406/how-to-update-refresh-specific-item-in-recyclerview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189371/using-notifyitemremoved-or-notifydatasetchanged-with-recyclerview-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503158/how-to-update-a-specific-item-cardview-in-recyclerview-onactivityresult), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688651/update-text-within-card-view-list), etc, but none of these solutions worked for me.

**UserPostsAdapter:**

```
public class UserPostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserPostsAdapter.PostsViewHolder> {

    private List<UserPosts> postItems;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private static final String TAG = UserPosts.class.getSimpleName();

    class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userPostsTitle, userPostsDate, userPost, textViewStars, textViewComments;
        ImageView imageViewDisplayComments, imageViewReply, imageViewCommentStar;
        String pCcontactId, postId;

        PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userPostsTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostsTitle);
            userPostsDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPostsDate);
            userPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPost);

            textViewStars = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStars);
            textViewComments = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewComments);

            imageViewCommentStar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCommentStar);
            imageViewDisplayComments = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDisplayComments);
            imageViewReply = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewReply);
        }
    }

    public UserPostsAdapter(List<UserPosts> postsList, Context context) {
        this.postItems = postsList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UserPostsAdapter.PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_user_post, parent, false);

        return new UserPostsAdapter.PostsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final UserPostsAdapter.PostsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final UserPosts post = postItems.get(position);

        db = new SQLiteHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        final String currentUserId = user.get("uid");

        if (post.getTitle() != null && !post.getTitle().isEmpty()) {
            holder.userPostsTitle.setText(post.getTitle());
        } else {
            holder.userPostsTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.userPostsDate.setText(post.getCreatedDateTime());
        holder.userPost.setText(post.getPostedText());
        if (Integer.parseInt(post.getLikesNumber()) > 0) {
            holder.textViewStars.setText(post.getLikesNumber());
        }
        holder.textViewComments.setText(post.getCommentsNumber());

        holder.pCcontactId = post.getUserId();
        final String postId = holder.postId = post.getId();

        if (post.getFavouritePost()) {
            holder.imageViewCommentStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_star_ppdcolor);
        } else {
            holder.imageViewCommentStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon_star_outline_ppdcolor);
        }

        holder.imageViewCommentStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            boolean isPressed = post.getFavouritePost();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isPressed) {
                    ApiInterface apiService =
                        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                    Call<DefaultResponse> call = apiService.removePostFavourite(currentUserId, postId);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                            boolean success = response.body().isSuccess();

                             onFavouriteClicked(position);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    ApiInterface apiService =
                        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

                    Call<DefaultResponse> call = apiService.addPostFavourite(currentUserId, postId);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                            boolean success = response.body().isSuccess();

                             onFavouriteClicked(position);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {                           
                            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
                isPressed = !isPressed;
            }
        });

        holder.imageViewDisplayComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        holder.imageViewReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder addCommentBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View addCommentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_add_comment_reply, null);
                final EditText addCommentReplyEditText = (EditText) addCommentView.findViewById(R.id.addCommentReplyEditText);
                FloatingActionButton imageViewCommentReply = (FloatingActionButton) addCommentView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCommentReply);

                addCommentBuilder.setView(addCommentView);
                final AlertDialog addCommentReply = addCommentBuilder.create();
                addCommentReply.show();

                imageViewCommentReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (!addCommentReplyEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        addCommentReply.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    R.string.failure,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFavouriteClicked(int position) {
        UserPosts post = postItems.get(position);
        post.setFavouritePost(!post.getFavouritePost());
        postItems.set(position, post);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postItems.size();
    }
}
```

**Cardview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/userPostsCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userPostsTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SpUsage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userPostsDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/userPostsTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/aluminum"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SpUsage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userPost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/userPostsDate"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/userPost"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#B6B6B6" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/idLLUserPostsFooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="9">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewCommentStar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/star"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewStars"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewDisplayComments"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/comments"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/comment_multiple_outline_ppdcolor" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewComments"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:padding="5dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewReply"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/reply"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/reply_ppdcolor" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userAppId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/number_zero"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userContactId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/number_zero"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```